# Pass session id to URL JSP page in Struts 2

Tags: java, redirect, struts2, parameter-passing, struts

I have a login page and welcome page,

here is `struts.xml` file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>

<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" /> 
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory" />  

<package name="Authentiate" extends="struts-default">

<global-results>

<result name="error">/error.jsp</result>

</global-results>

<action name="loginAuthenticate*" class="com.authenticate.actions.LoginAuthenticate" method="{1}">

<result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>
<result name="redirectRegister" type="redirect">/registration.jsp</result>

</action>

</package>

</struts>
```

how can  I append `sessionid` to the `welcome.jsp` when I return success result from action class in `struts.xml` as the following

```
http://myopenidhost.com/openid/welcome.jsp?sessionid=swe234323xghf346rrg34r4
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case when you submit your page use below in your javascript function:

you will declare hidden field in your page and assign jsessionId from your action to this hidden.

```
function abc(){

  var jsessionId=document.<hiddenFieldName>.value;
  document.action="welcomePage.jsp?sessionId="+jsessionId;
  document.submit();

}
```

I don't know what are you trying to achieve but yaa its a kind of Get request and you can see this generated id in your URL

if i am not wrong this is the way to append values in URL..
Please let me know if this helps...if not the i need exact criteria what you want to achieved.

Comment: http://myopenidhost.com/openid/welcome.jsp?name=hello&user=pavan  how can i result to the above  page because i am using result type=success and calling just welcome.jsp but i am not able to append the query string.

Comment: Pavan, Can you please tell me your criteria...i wanted to know so that could give you the correct solution...there is couple of way to do this. i know you wanted to add these values but why and for what purpose, if you clear this. perhaps i would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the result that returns a parameter

```xml
<result>
  <param name="location">/welcome.jsp</param>
  <param name="sessionId">${sessionId}</param>
</result>
```

in the action you should initialize the parameter before return result

```java
public class LoginAuthenticate extends ActionSupport {

  private String sessionId;

  public String getSessionId() {
    return sessionId;
  }

  public String execute() {

    //action code ...
 
    sessionId =  ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession().getId();
    return SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

you can read more about [Result Configuration](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/result-configuration.html) and about [dynamic results](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/result-configuration.html#dynamic-results).

Answer (score -2):

If you are trying to put your login details into the Session, use SessionAware interface, if not then let me know..

Comment: i like to append the query string to the result page ...as http://myopenidhost.com/openid/welcome.jsp?name=hello&user=pavan